# Removing margin,padding properties using Regular expression in java

Tags: java, css, regex

i have a css file and i want to remove all margin properties(left,right,bottom) and   padding(left,right) properties using regular expresion in java.please help me with this

this is my css

```
.calibre {
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 20pt;
        margin-right: 20pt;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        text-align: justify
        }
```

and output will be like this

```
.calibre {
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 1em;
        text-align: justify
        }
```

Comment: Use `^\s*(?:margin|padding).*$`  to match those lines.

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you. 2) I suspect this is yet another "Don't use RegEx for this" type question.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
String str = ".calibre {"+
     "   background-color: white;"+
     "   display: block;"+
     "   font-family: Times New Roman;"+
     "   font-size: 1em;"+
     "   margin-bottom: 0;"+
     "   margin-left: 20pt;"+
     "   margin-right: 20pt;"+
     "   margin-top: 0;"+
     "   padding-left: 0;"+
     "   padding-right: 0;"+
     "   text-align: justify"+
     "   }";


     System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(margin|padding).+?;", ""));
```

It printed:

```
.calibre {   background-color: white;   display: block;   font-family: Times New Roman;   font-size: 1em;                     text-align: justify   }
```